# Lubrication Theory Question

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I am consideringflow between a rigid cylinder parallel to a rigid horizontal stationary surface. Assuming that we can apply the lubrication limit (so that the cylinder is very close to the surface) I cannot understand why the net fluid force acting on the surface has no component perpendicular to it.

Could someone please help me understand!

Comment: Is that what your analysis shows?  If so, it is wrong.

Comment: It's part of the question!

Comment: why don't you just write down the appropriate lubrication equations for the situation and see how it plays out?